# How do I bind a SQL bit field to a True/False combobox or listbox?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, combobox, binding

I store True/False values as bit fields in SQL Server. The fields are nullable. **What is the XAML syntax to bind a bit field to a WPF combo box so the user can choose True/False or blank (null)?**

By the way, I'm binding to a strongly-typed dataset/datatable. Drag and drop binding has simplified binding to other datatypes. I certainly don't mind editing the XAML, but I'm wondering if drag and drop can be made to work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to create a value converter (a class which implements the `IValueConverter` interface) which can translate the value of a bit field to a boolean value. Part of the problem, out of the box, is that how do you represent a null value as a boolean state? That typically depends on the business process or rules.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a suggestion for anyone else who comes across this issue (without having to do the XAML stuff), I did the following using Linq (VB 2008):

```
Private Sub BindMyCombo()
    Dim yesNo As String() = {"No", "Yes"}   'Or false, true or nay, yay -whatever

    Dim bits = From bit In yesNo _
               Select New With { _
                   .BitVal = Cbool(Array.IndexOf(yesNo, bit)), _
                   .BitText = bit _
               }

    With Me.myBitComboBox
        'Clear anything in the combo first if necessary...
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .Items.Clear()
        'New binding in case there are more "bits" to be used elsewhere in your form
        .BindingContext = New BindingContext
        .DataSource = bits.ToList
        .DisplayMember = "BitText"
        .ValueMember = "BitVal"
    End With

End Sub
```

After that it's just a matter of doing the binding with the dataset. When you do, specify that when the bit value is null to set the combos selectedValue to blank or nothing, for example...

```
With Me.myBitComboBox
    .DataBindings.Clear()
    .DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", myDataSetName, "myBitFieldName", _
                      True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, Nothing))
    .SelectedValue = IIf(mdDataSetName.myBitFieldName.ToString = "", "", _
                         myDataSetName.myBitFieldName)
End With
```

I hope this helps anyone else that comes across this issue (like me).